# kaminari paginate via ajax ,remote = true is not affect on view in rails 3

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

Hello i am using kaminari gem for pagination and i want to do paginatation via ajax .

**index.html.haml**

```
#abc
 = render :partial => 'anything/anything_lists', collection: @anything_upcoming, as: :anything_schedule
#paginator
 = paginate @anything_upcoming, :remote => true, :param_name => "anything_upcoming_page"
```

**index.js.haml**

```
$('#abc').html('#{escape_javascript render(partial: "anything/anything_lists")}');
$('#paginator').html('#{escape_javascript(paginate(@anything_upcoming, :remote => true, :param_name => "anything_upcoming_page").to_s)}');
```

controller file:

```
@anything_upcoming = AnythingSchedule.anything_upcoming.page(params[:anything_upcoming_page]).per(Settings.pagination.per_page)

respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end
```

view source shows data-remote = true but log shows Website::EventsController#index as HTML. 
so what i am missing here.

**Edit**: i am doing some experiment on js file and i convert index.js.haml to index.js.erb and only one time i get ajax request and also shows calling JS on logs . and i redo again then as usual not get ajax request .

**Final Edit**
application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require ckeditor-jquery
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap-datepicker.min
//= require bootstrap-timepicker.min
//= require chosen.jquery.min
//= require jquery.popupoverlay
//= require common
//= require ace-elements.min
//= require registrations
//= require courses
//= require instructors
//= require jsapi
//= require donation
//= require workshops
//= require nav_settings_dropdown
//= require events
//= require event_schedules
//= require manage_home
//= require jquery.blockUI
//= require rails
```

**Gem file**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.17'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem "rails_config", "~> 0.3.3"

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'jammit'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "kaminari", "~> 0.14.1"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you must have forgotten to include the `application.js` in your layout file

OR

you are using another js or layout then the default one. Please check this

**Reason**:

The syntax for the pagination is correct

```
= paginate @anything_upcoming, :remote => true, :param_name => "anything_upcoming_page"
```

you have also included `jquery-rails` gem and also included the libraries in `application.js`

and you are saying `data-remote = true` is applying to the element. So the only problem I guess left is above one.